# Laravel AJAX getting all records in one JSON request

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to edit record in my database using ajax, my code is working fine, but i have to mention each column by name, how i can get same result without typing all columns name.

**Edit Controller:** i am using columns name [efirst,esecond etc] i want to pass everything from database without mentioning name

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'id' => $teacher->id,
            'efirst' => $teacher->efirst,
              'esecond' => $teacher->esecond,
        ]);
    }
```

**Edit.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $(".table-container").on("click touchstart", ".edit-btn", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "lists/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#esecond-not-found').remove();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#update-id").val(data['id']);
                $("#update-efirst").val(data['efirst']);
                $("#update-esecond").val(data['esecond']);
                $('#update-form').show();
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**View:**

```
<form method="post" id="update-form">
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="update-id">
  <div class="">
    <label for="efirst">efirst</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="efirst" id="update-efirst">   
         <label for="esecond">esecond body</label>
           <textarea name="esecond" class="form-control" id="update-esecond" rows="6"></textarea>
 </div>
    <div class="">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  id="update-submit">Update</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you just return ```return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'teacher' => $teacher
        ]);```

Comment: @DinoNumić it returns empty form, what about edit.js? what should i write on columns name?

Comment: In a similar way you did before. But now you are returning a teacher object so it will be ```$("#update-efirst").val(data.teacher.efirst);``` and so on.

Comment: @DinoNumić Thanks worked, but i have so many column, each field name is matching column name, is there any shorter method without writing every column?

Comment: You can do something like ```let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
                            teacher.forEach(item => {
                                $("#"+item[0]).val(item[1]);
                            });```

Comment: sorry it returns nothing. i guess above method is correct one so i am going to mark this question as complete.

Comment: please answer below so i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A teacher object can be passed instead of writing every table field

```
return response()->json([ 'status' => 'success', 'teacher' => $teacher ]);
```

So in order for this code to work the id of the form needs to match the name of the column

```
let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher); 
teacher.forEach(item => { $("#"+item[0]).val(item[1]); });
```

Let's say we have four inputs

```
<input id="data1" type="text" class="form-control">
<input id="data2" type="text" class="form-control">
<input id="data3" type="text" class="form-control">
<input id="data4" type="text" class="form-control">
```

and you do this

```
success: function (data) {
    let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
    teacher.forEach(item => {
       console.log(item)
       $("#"+item[0]).val(item[1]);
    });
}
```

the console log gives the following

```
(2) ["data1", "test1"]
(2) ["data2", "test2"]
(2) ["data3", "test3"]
(2) ["data4", "test4"]
```

you get an array of arrays that you can loop where the index position 0 is your input id and the index position 1 is your value.